# IIS Hangs on ExecuteRequestHandler

Tags: azure, iis, iis-7

I've encountered a problem with IIS.

The problem is the following:

- Sometimes (intermittent issue) IIS hangs a request in a state called `ExecuteRequestHandler`, and it spends ~85% of the time.

I couldn't figure out why. Tried everything what I've found in forums, nothing helped. I'm using azure for my backend server and another azure server I have my database.

[image]

Can somebody explain what exactly this ExecuteRequestHandler step in a request lifecycle?

I didn't find a good explanation about what this step is doing. Is it executing my code already or is it a pre-task in the lifecycle? The reason I'm asking it to be able to detect where the problem is.

Comment: This question is duplicated already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131559/web-api-requests-queueing-up-forever-on-iis-in-state-executerequesthandler

Answer (score 1):

That's when the application code executes.

When it receives a request, IIS creates an `IRequest` object to represent it, and also creates an `IHttpHandler` to handle it, the exact class depending on the technology (`DefaultHttpHandler`, `MvcHandler`, ...).

There are many steps to completely handle a request, the core one being the `HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.Execute` method calling `ProcessRequest` on the `IHttpHandler`.

Comment: thank you man! Was looking around for the documentation but haven't find the right one which explains things like you did. Do you have any link to a relevant documentation?

Comment: Sorry, no. It's from personal knowledge, and I check the exact code with Reflector.

Comment: Digging into my gard drive, I found http://cdn.nitrix-reloaded.com/publicdocs/asp.net_life_cycle_cheatsheet.pdf and http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/747/http-request-lifecycle-events-iis-pipeline-aspnet.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciated!